# Achieving loose coupling

Tags: design, dependencies, class-diagram, coupling, cohesion

My scenario involves the following classes:

[image]

I have three types of `Peer` that creates a `RegistryType` instance because its methods are needed. Same for `Identity` class. Each `PeerType` need 0 or all the `RegistryType` methods in order to accomplish their work. Every `Peer` is then run by creating a `Server` instance that makes use of one of the methods defined by the `Peer` by passing a callback.

What I'm trying to achieve is to solve the tight coupling between the `PeerType` classes and the `RegistryType` class. My idea is to define a general `Peer` class from which every type inherits and define the dependency with the `RegistryType` there.

The target language is Python so either constructing the `Peer`s with a `RegistryType` or a `Registry` is ok.

Even after defining a new `Peer` class to encapsulate the `RegistryType` I reckon the two classes are still tight coupled so (maybe) a solution would be to pass a `RegistryType` instance to the `Peer` class instead of constructing it inside its constructor.

I hope to receive some great suggestions. Thanks.

EDIT1: I'll try to be more specific.

[image]

Every `PeerType` implements some logic that is passed as argument to the `run` method of the `Server`. This method depends also on the `OTT_RPC` class because it needs the `callback_ottrpc` function to create the `HandshakeServer` and accomplish the handshake (`start_handshake`).

My first problem is that, each peer type is run by a class `Server`, but `Holder` offers two different services that should be passed to the `run` method in contrast `Verifier` offers only one, so I need to solve this inconsistency.

Second, the circular dependency between `Server`, `HandshakeServer` and `OTT_RPC`.

Comment: I find the question very abstract. For one all of your classes have very abstract names, and you didn't describe what the classes are doing, so that gives very little context. 
Secondly you state your want to solve tight coupling, but not how it affects you. Tight coupling isn't necessarily a bad thing, but it can get in the way of making changes later on. Without knowing what the kind of problems you are running into, it is hard to just solve 'tight coupling'.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: Tight/loose coupling does not mean what you think it means. Having three classes have a reference to a particular type is not an instance of tight coupling.

Comment: "Tight coupling is when a group of classes are highly dependent on one another"

Comment: I don’t understand the inconsistency.  I don’t see any circular dependency. Why don’t you ask a new question?

Comment: The `Server` class should offer a service provided by a `Peer`, the problem of this design is that if a `Peer` (see `Issuer`) offers two methods, then the `Server` should be able to offer two services based on what messages it receives. The problem is that I can pass only one `callback_peer`.

Answer (score 1):

Well [Helena](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/344463/helena) is [right](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/426055/achieving-loose-coupling#comment937986_426055), this is very abstract. But consider use of the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

[image]

Here `Peer` abstracts away knowledge of the different Peer types. So long as that is possible then the Strategy Pattern will achieve a coupling improvement because Peer hides PeerType details.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: I like your diagram style, what tool did you make it with?